# Babel doesn't update the change in plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am using babel with jest for testing nodejs and instrumentation. The problem I am facing is babel is somehow caching(my guess) the transformed code and doesn't update even after changes in plugins code. The reasoning behind my guess is if I run jest with new test, it shows the change. But after the first time, it shows the same output, even though I have changed the custom plugin code in babel.

This is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  const presets = [];
  const plugins = [
    [require(`./babel-instrumentor.js`)],
    [require("@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs").default],
  ];

  /** this is just for minimal working purposes,
   * for testing larger applications it is
   * advisable to cache the transpiled modules in
   * node_modules/.bin/.cache/@babel/register* */
  api.cache(false);

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

And this is the babel-instrumentor.js

```
console.log("Loaded babel plugin");
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {  
  return {
    name: "log-functions",
    visitor: {
      Function: {
        enter(path) {       
          let name = "anon";   
          if (path.node.id) 
            name = path.node.id.name;  
          console.log(path.node.body);
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```

I also couldn't find any cache folder in node_modules which is supposed to be in
`node_modules/.bin/.cache/@babel/register`